# Silverlight only makes one http request

Tags: c#, silverlight, caching, browser, httpwebrequest

I'm working on a Silverlight app which among other things makes Http requests in which it uploads a zip file from the web server. The zip file is picked up from the web server every n:th minute, a behavior controlled by a timer.

I've tried using the `WebClient` and `HttpWebRequest` classes with the same result. The request only reaches the web server the first time. The second, third, ..., time the request is sent and a response will occur. However, the request never reaches the web server...

```
    void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try 
        {
            HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.CreateHttp(_serverUrl + "channel.zip");
            req.Method = "GET";

            req.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(WebComplete), req);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }

    void WebComplete(IAsyncResult a)
    {

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)a.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.EndGetResponse(a);
        Stream stream = res.GetResponseStream();

        byte[] content = readFully(stream);
        unzip(content);

    }
```

Is there some kind of browser caching issue here?
I want every request I make to go all the way to the web server.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the browser may be caching the request. If you want to disable that, you can either modify the server to send a `Cache-Control: no-cache` header, or you can append some sort of uniquifier to the URL that will prevent the browser from caching the request:

```
void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try 
    {
        HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.CreateHttp(_serverUrl + "channel.zip?_=" + Environment.TickCount);
        req.Method = "GET";

        req.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(WebComplete), req);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Chances are your timer freezes, not the web request. Put a `Debug.WriteLine` in your timer event, make sure it gets called more than once.

It's also a bad idea to use timers for background tasks. Instead of a timer it's a better option to create a background task that sleeps between requests. This way even too long of server request won't cause calls to overlap.

Try something in the lines of:

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.DoWork+=(s,a)=>{
   try{
      while (true)// or some meaningful cancellation condition is false
      {
          DownloadZipFile();
          Sleep(FiveMinutes);
          // don't update UI directly from this thread
      }
   } catch {
      // show something to the user so they know automatic check died
   }
};
worker.RunAsync();
```